# Opendaylight YANG tools search path

Tags: openflow, opendaylight

I am developing a service for opendaylight (carbon). I want to use ietf-access-control-list@2017-06-16.yang instead of the existing ietf-access-control-list.yang that comes with the ODL Carbon distribution. How can I direct the yangtool to pick up this yang file instead of the other one? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK it is simple enough. Just place the updated yang file in api/src/main/yang and yangtool will pick it up from there.